# Powershell - o uso de wildcard ou coisa semelhante em Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration

Tags: email, powershell

Estou há tempos tentando descobrir sozinho, a partir de pesquisa em vários sites, foruns etc uma solução que julgo ser relativamente simples, mas sem sucesso.

Eu gostaria de bloquear mails para um determinado usuário do Exchange, mas não pelo endereço inteiro, mas por parte do nome de domínio.

Vamos supor que eu tenha recebido mails de usuários diferentes, ou do mesmo usuário, mas que ele mude continuamente seu domínio.

Uma hora seria, por exemplo,

...@mail21.us4.mcsv.net

depois chega como

...@mail68.atl71.mcdlv.net

outra hora vem como

...@mail21.wdc03.rsgsv.net

e outra hora aparece como

...@mail22.wdc01.mcdlv.net

e, repetindo parte de um dos domínios acima, como

...@mail67.us4.mcsv.net

Eu gostaria de, pelo menos, bloquear o que chegar como 'mcsv.net', que já ajudaria bastante.

Ou seja, a instrução do PowerShell poderia ser como

```
Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity $usuario -BlockedSendersAndDomains @{Add="*.mcsv.net"}
```

Até agora, eu vi que posso marcar, por exemplo,

```
 Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Identity $usuario -BlockedSendersAndDomains @{Add="mail22.wdc01.mcdlv.net"}
```

porque, no caso, este seria o nome completo do domínio.

Mas, como muda o tempo todo, isto não adianta muito.

Teria como usar wildcard para este problema? A instrução, o comando de bloqueio em si, não permite.

Grato

Mauro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código abaixo está longe de uma boa programação, mas poderá ser útil para quem precisar de uma luz.

```
cls #limpa a tela para evitar confusão na resposta
$UserCredential = Get-Credential -Credential "meuUsuarioComPoderes@meuDominioNaMicrosoft.com" #login/endereço do usuário com poderes totais
$usuario="usuarioAlvo@meuDominio.com" #endereço da caixa postal a ser modificada
$dominioBloqueio="mcsv.net" #parte de nome de domínio que será bloqueado
$pasta=$usuario+":\Lixo Eletrônico" #para para direcionar as mensagens bloqueadas
$nomeDaRegra="REJEITAR" #nome da regra. Um nome qualquer. O que desejar
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential    $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
$resultado=Get-Mailbox $usuario | Get-MailboxPermission -User "loginDoUsuarioAdministrador"
$direito="FullAccess" #No caso, tem de ser este direito completo
$booTemDireitosTotais=$false #flag que vai indicar se o direito já existe
ForEach($i in $resultado){#Procura todos os direitos existentes
if($i.AccessRights -eq $direito){
$booTemDireitosTotais=$true #existindo, marca o flag
}#if($i
}#forEach
$regras = Get-InboxRule -MailBox $usuario
$contador=0
foreach($i in $regras){
$contador=$contador+1
if($i.name -eq $nomeDaRegra){
$booRegraExiste=$true
}#$if($i.name
}
if ($booTemDireitosTotais){
#---
        if($contador -eq 0){
            Write-Host "O agente tem direitos totais na caixa-postal do usuário, mas não existe sequer uma regra regristrada. Basta criar a regra."
            New-InboxRule -name $nomeDaRegra -MailBox $usuario -HeaderContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -FromAddressContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -MoveToFolder $pasta -Confirm:$false
            Get-InboxRule  -Identity $nomeDaRegra -Mailbox $usuario
            Write-Host "Veja a propriedade Name acima para se certificar de que foi dada a permissão e criada a regra."
            } else{
            Write-host "Existem regras. Mas será que existe a que queremos?"
            #Há alguma regra, mas será que queremos?
                if($booRegraExiste){
                    Write-Host "A permissão está dada, a regra $nomeDaRegra existe, portanto basta altera-la"
                    Set-InboxRule -Identity $nomeDaRegra -Mailbox $usuario -HeaderContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -FromAddressContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -MoveToFolder $pasta -Confirm:$true
                    Get-InboxRule  -Identity $nomeDaRegra -Mailbox $usuario
                Write-Host "Veja a propriedade Name acima para se certificar de que foi alterada a regra."
                }else{
                    #a regra Não existe. Cria
                     Write-Host " A permissão está dada, mas a regra $nomeDaRegra NÃO EXISTE. Cria."
                    New-InboxRule -name $nomeDaRegra -MailBox $usuario -HeaderContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -FromAddressContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -MoveToFolder $pasta -Confirm:$false
                    Get-InboxRule  -Identity $nomeDaRegra -Mailbox $usuario
                    Write-Host "Veja a propriedade Name acima para se certificar de que foi alterada a regra."
                }#if ($booRegraExiste
        }#if($contador
#---
}else{
    Write-Host "O agente NÃO TEM direitos totais na caixa-postal do usuário. Vai ter de alterar esta configuração. Em seguida, criar a regra"
        Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $usuario -User "LoginUsuarioComPoderes" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
        New-InboxRule -name $nomeDaRegra -MailBox $usuario -HeaderContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -FromAddressContainsWords $dominioBloqueio -MoveToFolder $pasta -Confirm:$false
        Get-InboxRule  -Identity $nomeDaRegra -Mailbox $usuario
Write-Host "Veja a propriedade Name acima para se certificar de que foi dada a permissão e criada a regra."
}#if($booTem

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Para os que não desejam usar o PowerShell, encontrei algo bastante valioso, usando o próprio Centro de Administração do Exchange: há regras no fluxo de mail que permitem, bastando preencher campos, dizer qual filtro usar.

Neste último caso, eu fiz o seguinte, de modo a ficar para TODAS as caixas postais do meu domínio:

- 1 - Entrei no site do Exchange, no Centro de Administração Office365
- 2 - Fui para a seção Administrador
- 3 - Escolhi Exchange
- 4 - Escolhi Fluxo de Emails
- 5 - Escolhi Regras
- 6 - Cliquei no botão com o sinal de adição (+) para criar uma nova regra
- 7 - Dei um nome a ela
- 8 - No campo 'Aplicar Esta Regra Se...', escolhi 'O endereço do remetente inclui...'
- 9 - Preenchi parte do nome do domínio para não mais receber mails deles. A cada um diferente, fui pressionando o sinal de adição dessa janela.
- 10 - No campo 'Faça o seguinte...' eu marquei 'Excluir a mensagem sem notificar o destinatário ou o remetente' e também mais uma ação com 'Enviar o relatório de incidentes para ' (aqui eu pus meu mail corporativo).
- 11 - Salvar.

Abraço a todos,
Mauro